# Error: Execution failed for task app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788406/executing-tasks-appgeneratedebugsources-in-project

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` inside build.gradle of module

Comment: I am getting the below message when I change that

Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.example.flutter_getx' in default config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do below things:

- Take a backup of your project after following this step

1) Update your android Gradle plugin 
2) Goto Refactor > migrate to androidX

After Build & Run your project

Comment: This answer is too unrelated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

> File -> Invalidate caches/Restart

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a project when l merge unrelated histories using git. The merge left conflicts unresolved in the project. What l did was to search for `<<<<<<< HEAD` and fix all merge conflicts in the project.